# GC Rules : how to findout a java object is eligible for garbage collection or not

Tags: java

Anyone point me the set of defined rules to find out the eligibility for garbage collection of java objects and a simple example for that .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objects are eligible for GC'ing once they're no longer *reachable* from any thread.

An object O is reachable from another object A if either:

- A has a reference to O, or
- A has a reference to an object from which O is reachable

So if you had: `class Foo { Bar x = new Bar(); }` and `class Bar { Bar y = new Baz(); }`,
and one of your threads had an instance of `Foo`, then the instances of `Foo`, `Bar` and `Baz` would all be reachable and not eligible for GC. (The thread has a reference to the `Foo` instance, which has a reference to the `Bar` instance, which has a reference to the `Baz` instance).

If you then set `x` to `null` (or another object) in your instance of `Foo`, neither the `Bar` or `Baz` instances would be reachable any more. (The thread has a reference to the `Foo` instance still, and the `Bar` instance has a reference to the `Baz` instance, but the `Foo` instance no longer holds a reference to the `Bar` instance). Both the `Bar` and `Baz` instances would therefore both be eligible for GC.